# JComponent not being drawn on JLayeredPane, JPanel is

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent, jlayeredpane

I've added a `JLayeredPane` to a `JFrame`. To said pane i've added a `JComponent` with overloaded `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, which calls `super.paintComponent(g)` among other things. The `JComponent` also has `setBackground(Color.RED)` and `setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100)` in its constructor.

The problem is, the `JComponent` isn't being drawn at all it seems. However, if i change the class being extended by the `JComponent` to `JPanel`, it works just fine.

Does it matter at all? I would like to know why it works this way, it seems like extending `JPanel` when i don't care for its additions is just unnecessary overhead.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The JComponent also has setBackground(Color.RED)

On its own that will do nothing.

A JComponent has no default painting code, so invoking super.paintComponent() will NOT cause any background to be painted.

If you want to paint the background you need to add your own custom painting code:

```
g.seColor( getBackground() );
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```